# Android App cannot connect to local server

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which is dependent on a node server. I want to be able to test both my android app and node server locally.

I have my node server running on my computer and try to access it from my android application (on my physical device) causes a 404 error code.

However the exact same code will work if I emulate android on my computer. Also the server works when I access it from my cell phone's browser.

I try to use the following code to detect the server in case the IP of my computer ever changes.

```
            byte[] ip = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(((WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.WIFI_SERVICE)).getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()).array();
            for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                ip[3] = (byte)i;
                try {
                    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                    System.out.println("trying " + addr.getHostAddress());
                    if(addr.isReachable(5000)) {
                        System.out.println("yes");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And it does not say yes for my computer's IP address.

Am I thinking of this wrong? Is there another way? Are there settings I am not thinking about?

Comment: Does this code snippet work when executed from a console Java application on your computer?  Maybe a port is currently being blocked.  This could explain why the web browser can get through by not the Android app.

Comment: Are you using any proxy on your computer ?

Comment: @SharpEdge i have not set up any proxies...is there any way to check?

Comment: If you're using windows, then open internet explorer>Tools>Connections>LAN Settings and there check if the proxy is checked or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen using this code to get the ip address`byte[] ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();` the code prints yes for a console java application

Comment: @SharpEdge the option is not checked

Comment: There is nothing in your code that tries to access a node server as far as i can see. Also you did not indicate where you got that 404 in your code.

Comment: And where is that code running? On pc or phone?

Comment: And what is `controller`?

Comment: @greenapps controller is an activity...I run the code in both emulated (pc) and physical devices...the snipet doesn't say yes when the IP address is the same as my local (it says yes for emulated) server's is essentially the 404 I get...hard coding and or using the uri class still gives a 404...just reread the post as most of your questions have been answered

Comment: Did you miss any port number?

Comment: Did you try to actually connect to the server via HTTP, e.g. using HttpURLConnection? InetAddress.isReachable() may not work correctly on Android because it uses ICMP echo packets ("ping") and this may require root privileges. Also, testing for reachability doesn't guarantee that there is an HTTP port (or any other port) open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that there is a command for forward requests from your mobile device to your computer which makes it so that you don't have to write the ip checking code. Simply use the following adb command

```
adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

where 8080 is your port number, the left is the port your phone is hitting and the right is the port running on your server so you can mix and match those numbers

Of course you can only run this command while your phone is hardwired and have to run it each time you disconnect your phone.